# Exclude line ranges when using Sed

Tags: sed

With Sed, I want to use "!" to exclude lines that matches "he". Here is an example.

```
echo "hello" |sed "/he/!s/hello/hi/"
```

To my surprise,  my ubuntu 14 returns

`"bash !s/hello/hi: event not found"`

error. Any ideas? How could I exclude line ranges corresponding to a pattern with Sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *history expansion* enabled.  You need to disable it with `set +H`.

#### Example

Let's enable *history expansion* and run your command:

```
$ set -H
$ echo "hello" |sed "/he/!s/hello/hi/"
bash: !s/hello/hi/: event not found
```

Now, let's disable it and observe that the command now runs correctly and without error:

```
$ set +H
$ echo "hello" |sed "/he/!s/hello/hi/"
hello
```

#### Alternative

If you want to keep *history expansion* enabled, then single-quote your string:

```
$ set -H
$ echo "hello" |sed '/he/!s/hello/hi/'
hello
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not know there is a difference between single and double quotes when using sed...

Comment: @wad Actually, to clarify, the shell (bash) processes your commands __before__ passing the result to `sed`.  The quoting issues that we are dealing with here are shell issues.